# How to prevent enter from turning into empty space?

Tags: html, css, dom

This is something that has been bugging me since the first time I learned HTML.

```
<style>
.test{
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:#aaa;
    padding:5px 10px;
    margin:0;
    border:0;
    }
</style>

<div class="test">Hello</div>
<div class="test">Woooorld</div>
<div class="test">HTML</div>
<div class="test">CSS</div>
```

[image]

I will definitely want to keep the elements in different lines, because else it becomes unreadable. But HTML turns the enters into spaces, which ruins the layout. Float causes a whole array of new problems or simply is not viable for what I am trying to do.

Is there really no better solution than to implement some hacky negative margins for everything except the first element?

Comment: This really has nothing to do with the enter key. It is how the DOM renders the DIV. The negative margins aren't really hacky. They are an intend way to do overlapping elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different ways to solve this problem.

link: http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

**1st Way:**

```
<div class="test">Hello</div><div
class="test">Woooorld</div><div
class="test">HTML</div><div
class="test">CSS</div>
```

or

```
<div class="test">Hello</div
><div class="test">Woooorld</div
><div class="test">HTML</div
><div class="test">CSS</div>
```

**2nd Way:**

```
<div class="test">Hello</div><!--
--><div class="test">Woooorld</div><!--
--><div class="test">HTML</div>
<div class="test">CSS</div>
```

**3rd Way:**
    use negative margins.

```
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
```

**4th way**
    Skip the closing tag

```
<div class="test">Hello
<div class="test">Woooorld
<div class="test">HTML
<div class="test">CSS</div>
```

**5th way**
    Set the font size to zero for a wrapper div.

**6th way**
Maybe they don't need to be inline-block at all, maybe they can just be floated one way or another.

Answer (score 1):

Just change your HTML slightly:

```
<div class="test">asdasd</div
><div class="test">asdasd</div
><div class="test">asdasd</div
><div class="test">asdasd</div>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fsr7J/). As all `<div>`-s in your current layout are `inline-block` elements, browsers are treating the whitespace between them as the same-class - inline - elements, allocating some visual space for them.

Comment: this would break if you add varying length texts inside divs.

Comment: With a fixed width for those elements - yes, of course. But it's a completely different problem - which, I'm pretty darn sure, is known to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to let the elements float instead of changing the HTML. CSS is for displaying.

Working:

```
<style>
.test{
    display:inline-block;
    float: left;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#aaa;
    }
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="test">asdasd</div>
<div class="test">asdasd</div>
<div class="test">asdasd</div>
<div class="test">asdasd</div>
```

Comment: Actually, there's exactly the same answer deleted by its author. ) While I agree that `float`-ing these elements is usually a better choice, it's not a universal solution - as some layouts just won't let you go that way. )

Comment: I know... but i hate to read this HTML code when the elements are just "weired". I prefer to read clean HTML and "clean" CSS, maybe with a comment in the CSS file

Comment: This usually happens when I'm making menus and I am using "text-align:center". In that case float does not work. It also tends to ruin the dynamic height of the element these are inside of.

Answer (score 1):

My own solution is to have on-the-fly HTML minification through the PHP script - it strips all newlines and tabs from the HTML source before sending it to the browser (unless said whitespace is inside an element that renders whitespace literally, such as a textarea or any element with `white-space:pre-wrap` or similar)

Answer (score 1):

Also should work...

```
<div class="test">asdasd</div><!--
--><div class="test">asdasd</div><!--
--><div class="test">asdasd</div><!--
--><div class="test">asdasd</div>
```

Comment: This also works as desired, and without breaking the tags. I'll probably use this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your divs inside a container div and set the container `font-size:0;`, then set the child divs `font-size:14pt` for example, This solves your issue.

And here is a working **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KuK7g/)**